# Cakephp - Paginating data from another model

Tags: cakephp, find

I am trying to do pagination from the accommodation controller but with data from the MemberWall model.

here is the code

```
Accommodation

$data = $this->Accommodation->Member->MemberWall->paginate('MemberWall');

MemberWall

var $paginate = array(
 'limit' => 4,
 'order' => array(
   'MemberWall.created' => 'asc'
 )
);
```

I get this error

```
SQL Error: 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use nea....   Query: paginate
```

Thanks, Alex

Answer (score -2, accepted):

1. The MemberWall $paginate array (your second snippet) looks like it's defined in member_walls_controller.php It will not be accessible from accommodations_controller.php
2. `$this->Accommodation->Member->MemberWall->paginate('MemberWall');` is calling a method on the MemberWall *model*. paginate() is a controller method.
3. Read [Custom-Query-Pagination](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#custom-query-pagination), particularly the last section.
4. I'm not sure that you can paginate that far down a relationship and it indicates to me that you probably need to rethink your datamodel and logic.
5. The [1.2 manual](http://book.cakephp.org/1.2/en/The-Manual/Common-Tasks-With-CakePHP/Pagination.html#custom-query-pagination) is better written on this topic.

Comment: I found the best way to get round this was to use js pagination. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 18):

Here is the REAL answer.

```
$data = $this->paginate($this->Accommodation->Member->MemberWall);
```

I had trouble finding this in the docs too. You can actually pass a model object into the paginate method.

Answer (score 8):

I've tried and it works in both ways:

`$this->paginate('MemberWall');`

`$this->paginate($this->Accommodation->Member->MemberWall);`

In my code I use something like;

`$this->loadModel('MemberWall');`

`$this->paginate = array(.....);`

`$data = $this->paginate('MemberWall');`

Comment: That's all good, but why load the model when it's already loaded. It's better to link to the model where it's already loaded than to load it a second time.

Comment: That's the point, the model is NOT already loaded or paginate would be associated to it. This is the more detailed solution. Especially if you want to change the `paginate` options. +1

Comment: @ChuckBurgess - Not really true... the model is already accessible, the reason OPs code didn't work is because paginate is a Controller method, not a model method.

Answer (score 0):

$this->paginate('MemberWall'); iirc is the way it works

Comment: I get this error, Controller::paginate() - can't find model MemberWall in controller AccommodationsController [CORE/cake/libs/controller/controller.php